# Custom Collection with DataBound Control or XML/XSL?

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt, asp-classic

I have to convert a module in classic ASP to ASP.NET 2.0. Basically it is a html form generated via XSL transformation. The figure shows the basic functionality.

[image]

In ASP.NET version:

1: The functionality will remain the same but the UI changes a lot. So existing XSL won't be reusable(may be logic can be used).

2: Data will be coming as XML. If really needed can be returned result-sets.

What I am thinking is:

1: Create a custom collection class and populate it with the data by reading the XML.
2: Bind it to a Repeater or similar DataBound control.

My Question:

1: Is the above approach worth implementing? Or

2: Should I use the XSL /XML approach as it is currently implemented. Do Ajax call and all that?

3: Is there any better approach then the above two?

Notes:

1: I am using .NET 2.0 and can't move to 4.0 or MVC.

2: When Submit button is clicked, I will need to loop through each rows and submit back the entered input. So I think server-side input controls would be good instead of plain html but any suggestions will be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go via creating a Custom Collection and loading xml values into that collection and then binding it to Repeater.

I have better control over the input controls and display this way and seems it will be easier in looping the Repeater Items while saving back the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can minimize the effort and re-use your current logic with the following approach.

1. Put a Literal control in your page.
2. Use xsl/xml to generate html and display that html in Literal control.
3. Then in a post-back event loop through Request.Form elements to get the input values.

Comment: Thanks for response. My first preference is using ASP.NET Controls unless there is any substantial drawback using them in compare to using XSL. And I am not sure how replacing div with Literal change much?

Comment: Literal is just for inserting plain html to your page. This way you will not have to make an ajax call to another page.